# Loading characters from array in mips

Tags: arrays, loops, assembly, mips

When you load character from an array in mip does the data still exist at that position in the array ? if not, how can you loop thru the array and get each character within the array ? thanks (:

Answer (score 1):

Though your question seem silly, it is actually a very legitimate question!

Form an outside perspective modern memories have a *non-destructive* readout.
This means that reading a memory location doesn't destroy the data held there.
**So reading from an array won't destroy the item read**.

Out of curiosity it is funny to note that internally, depending on the memory technology, reading may be a destructive operation (the common DRAM and the old Magnetic core memory are an example<sup>1</sup>) and that there exists (and existed) destructive memories.

MIPS could run in a system with destructive readout, that would be tricky however since MIPS is a Von Neumann architecture, instructions are read from the same memory where data are.
So reading an instruction would also destroy it.
Though one can arrange a mixed system where code is run from a non destructive memory and data is in a destructive one, such configuration is so unusual that you can safely assume that it wont never happen.

---

<sup>1</sup> Read-only memory like ROM, PROM and in general non-volatile memories have non destructive reading (so do Flash ROMs).  In general memory that stores "charges" have destructive readouts.

Comment: To say that a read from DRAM is destructive is a little misleading. DRAM certainly does not change its contents when read. On the contrary, every read refreshes the row being read. DRAM contents will self-destruct in the absence of read cycles or refresh cycles.

Comment: @user3386109 That's why I used *internally*. A read is an internal read (i.e. sensing) + a refresh. The internal read is destructive.